# partial caching a razor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, razor

In WebForm Controls I can cache the response of an individual control with an OutputCache line such as:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="240" VaryByParam="none" VaryByCustom="none" %>
```

How do I do the same with a Razor helper?

```
@Helper HelperName(Vars)
    ' Do stuff, and cache it, return from cache as per parameters etc
End Helper
```

Comment: Helpers are just functions to render snippets of HTML, not partial pages. Caching does not apply to Helpers.

Answer (score 2):

In Asp.Net Mvc 6 you can use `<cache>` tag helper to cache partial view.

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)">
    @Html.Partial("_WhatsNew")
    *last updated  @DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
</cache>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a child action, which will allow you utilize the `[OutputCache]` attribute in the same way as you would with the WebForm control.
2. Utilize `System.Runtime.Caching` for in-memory cache. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff477235%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

However, even if you go with #2, I'd recommend moving your code off into an actual `HtmlHelper` extension rather than using Razor Helpers. I'm not sure why in the world Microsoft even made those possible, but they should be avoided like the plague. They're not compiled until runtime, which means if you have a bug, you only find out about it when you visit the right page under the right circumstances, rather than being notified immediately during build. Worse, it's next to impossible to test a Razor helper, which makes it even more likely you'll introduce bugs that explode live.

Comment: `Helper`s are just functions in the compiled view. Set your project to precompile the views and compile errors will be spotted :)

Comment: That only works when publishing, and personally I prefer to know my code is broken before getting that far. Regardless, that does nothing about the problem of testing these, and we should all be testing our code, right? Right?!? ;) Plain and simple, they're an anti-pattern. There's better, more robust ways to accomplish the same thing, so use those instead.

Comment: Just suggesting terms like *plague* are not appropriate to describe what is basically a function-call-based snippet :) Most tools have uses.

Comment: Not Razor helpers, and I think the strength of my language is totally appropriate. There's nothing you can do with a Razor helper you can't do another way (a more robust way). They're not testable and they violate MVC (the pattern... logic should not exist in the view).

Comment: For tiny snippets of repeated parametized HTML they are appropriate and simpler than adding a HtmlHelper method. Again: *it just depends on the use*. I am not suggesting placing large amounts of code in them.

Comment: Been developing in MVC for years and never used one once. Done just fine. The point is that you have something that is not testable *and* violates the pattern the very framework took as its namesake, and there's no true *need* to ever use it. You can accomplish the same things in a myriad of other ways, all of which *are* testable and don't clutter the view. Just because you *can* shoot yourself in the foot, doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Again with the emotive terms... It's just "software options". I've been coding MVC since it came out and just happened to use a `Helper` today on a commercial project (for a paramatized header element). No testing required and the HTML is this case is in the page *where it belongs*. If you can't be trusted with a gun then by all means stick to a more limited set of options :)